# Dynamically query mongodb with golang

Tags: database, mongodb, go, nosql, mgo

I'm trying to query my mongodb database using golang (and the mgo library) with only one function, and the method I am currently using is:

```
er = c.Find(sel(items)).Sort("-createdAt").All(&result)
```

Where items is a map and the key is the name of the field I am searching inthe db, and the value is what I want to search by.

and sel() is:

```
func sel(query map[string]string) bson.M {
result := make(bson.M, len(query))
result[ ] = "$in"
for k, v := range query {
    result[k] = v
}
return result
```

currently it will return all of the results where at least one of the fields matches the input map. (So a logical OR) however I would like it to return the logical AND of these fields.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to modify the existing code or a new way of efficiently querying the database?

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate the *logical AND* behavior you desire? Matching all the fields, not any of them?

Comment: I am hoping to get a result where each value in the map matches the corresponding field in the database. So I would like it to be something like bson.M{"$and" : all of the k,v pairs}

Comment: So yes, matching all of the fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what this line is supposed to mean:

```
result[ ] = "$in"
```

As it is a compile-time error.

But the elements of the query document (the conditions) are in logical AND connection by default, so this is all it takes:

```
func sel(query map[string]string) bson.M {
    result := make(bson.M, len(query))
    for k, v := range query {
        result[k] = v
    }
    return result
}
```

If this gives you all the documents in the collection, then that means all the key-value pairs match all the documents. Experiment with simple filters to see that it works.

**Also note that the [`mgo`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo) package also accepts a wide range of maps and structs, not just [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#M).** Documentation of [`Collection.Find()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Find) has this to say about the allowed types:

> The document may be a map or a struct value capable of being marshalled with bson. The map may be a generic one using interface{} for its key and/or values, such as bson.M, or it may be a properly typed map. Providing nil as the document is equivalent to providing an empty document such as bson.M{}.

So you can use your map which is of type `map[string]string` without converting it:

```
err = c.Find(items).Sort("-createdAt").All(&result)
```

Comment: I forgot to remove that line before copying! Thank you. Also we just found a bug in the code from a colleague of mine that was causing our "query" problem that turns out wasn't even a db issue... Gotta love human error

Comment: @bagreeni Please see my edit. You don't even need this `sel()` conversion: you can just use your original `map[string]string` map without conversion!

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely helpful to know

Comment: @bagreeni I provided exact description (with reference) about what can be used as the query.